# (SQL) How to select the correct row for each group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a piece of data:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| first_name | last_name | family_id | is_primary | is_secondary |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| a          | b         |         1 |          1 |            0 |
| aa         | bb        |         1 |          0 |            0 |
| c          | d         |         1 |          0 |            0 |
| cc         | dd        |         1 |          0 |            0 |
| e          | f         |        10 |          0 |            0 |
| e          | f         |        10 |          0 |            1 |
| gg         | hh        |        10 |          0 |            1 |
| gg         | hh        |        10 |          0 |            0 |
| gg         | hh        |        10 |          0 |            0 |
| gg         | hh        |        10 |          0 |            0 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

What I want to do are:

- Group by family_id (So we will have two groups)
- For each group, if there are some rows that have `is_primary` equals 1, then choose a random row of them and get its first_name and last_name as the output of the group's two columns
- For each group, if there is no row that has `is_primary` equals 1, find a row (any row is ok) that has `is_secondary` equals to 1 and get its first_name and last_name as the output of the group's two columns

So based on the logic described above and the data, the correct result should be:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| family_id | first_name | last_name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|         1 | a          | b         |
|        10 | e          | f         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| family_id | first_name | last_name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|         1 | a          | b         |
|        10 | gg         | hh        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I write the query to get the correct result?

Below is the script to create the test table.

```
USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    first_name   VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    last_name    VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    family_id    INTEGER    NOT NULL,
    is_primary   INTEGER    NOT NULL,
    is_secondary INTEGER    NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('a','b',1,1,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('aa','bb',1,0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('c','d',1,0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('cc','dd',1,0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('e','f',10,0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('e','f',10,0,1);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('gg','hh',10,0,1);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('gg','hh',10,0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('gg','hh',10,0,0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('gg','hh',10,0,0);
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable;
```

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: Yes I have tried to solve it but failed. Let me update the question.

Comment: if you want first one result then it doesn't require any effort, simple use it : select family_id,min(first_name),min(last_name)
from mytable 
group by family_id

Comment: Is there any chance `is_primary` and `is_secondary` are both 1?

Comment: @Eric, Yes, in that case, `is_primary` takes precedence.

Comment: "choose randomly" drawn from what random distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by family_id order by is_primary desc, is_secondary desc) rn
    from mytable
    where is_primary+is_secondary = 1
)
select * from x where rn = 1
```

(thanks for the create & insert script)

EDIT:
As per OP comment (that both flags could be 1), change the WHERE clause to this:

```
where is_primary = 1 or (is_primary = 0 and is_secondary = 1)
```

Comment: As `OP` mentioned `is_primary` and `is_secondary` can both 1, the where condition need to change as `>=` 1

Comment: Also not choosing randomly (you can just order by something non-deterministic, like RAND)

Comment: @Caleth Any select without an explicit ORDER BY clause is non-deterministic by nature, don't you agree? Keep in mind that there is "random" and "random", with different levels of "randomness" and different associated cost. BTW, RAND() is not that random at all, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) would do better here.

Answer (score 1):

If the rows selected must be random, then use the following:

```sql
WITH primary_families AS (
    SELECT   family_id
            ,first_name
            ,last_name
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS r
    FROM familytable
    WHERE is_primary = 1
),
secondary_families AS (
    SELECT   family_id
            ,first_name
            ,last_name
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS r
    FROM familytable f
    WHERE is_secondary = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM familytable
        WHERE family_id = f.family_id
        AND is_primary = 1
    )
)

SELECT   f.family_id
        ,f.first_name
        ,f.last_name
FROM primary_families f
WHERE f.r = 1

UNION

SELECT   f.family_id
        ,f.first_name
        ,f.last_name
FROM secondary_families f
WHERE f.r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to your specific question, just an observation. If I had to develop a software or web application with such logic I would move it from SQL to the available programming language. Retrieve the interested data set, scan it, split in group and sort.